# Pandas groupby to count the number of instances

Tags: python, pandas

How to group my dataframe `dataset` by the column `default` using Pandas?

From the cheat sheet:

[image]

An this is my code:

```
dataset.groupby(by = "default")
```

Which returns:

```
<pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x7fb4ac4f2490>
```

Comment: The cheat sheet tells you that it returns a groupby object. If you want to return a frame or series preform some calculations on the groupby object: `dataset.groupby('default').size()`

Comment: google for "pandas groupby example"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seens you question is a little on the theoretical side, so I am going to explain to you how to do what you want and also what @It_is_Chris, meant on his comment.

So how does groupby work in Pandas?

A: The idea is pretty simple, imagine you are grouping by one column with two different values. Python will create "small data frames" filtered accordingly to the column being grouped. Such generated "small data frames" come out as groupby generator Objects, which to be honest is outside the given subject. But just think of them as "small separated data frames with each one having a given set of characteristics/attributes".

Now about your question, didnt quite catch what you want but I guess is just the amount of events, or the size of the dataframe. Nonetheless, just take a look at the [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) docs and you will be able to find out which method fits better

```
dataset.groupby(by = "default").count()
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it really helps a lot! As per the title of my question, I'm trying to count the number of instances. The cheat sheet should have an example of that, since an object without methods is of no use.

Comment: In this case them just use the count or size method like the given sample. That will probably help u